# Boton Mostrar mas en la edicion de un curso de Moodle fuera de posicion

Tags: moodle

Hola actulice a la version 3.9.7 de moodle pero desde que lo hice tengo un modulo para mostar mas o menos informacion cuando edito parametros de un curso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El boton que dice **Mostra'n més...** (Mostrar Mas)  me sale en el medio cuando deberia salirme abajo, en vewrsiones anteriores salia bien fue cuando actulice la version que sucede esto, he estado revisando el js (lib/form/amd/src/showadvanced.js) y el lib/formslib.php pero esta igual que el del git de moodle (3.9).

EL resultado esperado seria el suiguiente(3.5)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien ha tenido el mismo problema.

Saludos

Comment: No es la única diferencia entre ambas capturas. El `font-family` también es diferente, así como el `color` de algunos elementos. Esto puede ser debido a dos cosas: o bien la actualización ha introducido un archivo `.css` que se carga después que tu `style.css`, por lo que sobrescribe tu diseño personalizado. O bien se ha perdido toda comunicación con dicho diseño personalizado. Echa un vistazo al Inspector de Chrome, a ver si es que el CSS no se está aplicando, o si es que está siendo sobrescrito por otros parámetros importados desde algún otro `.css`.

Comment: Hola , disculpa no especifique, son campus diferentes y como tal el boton "Mostrar mas" solo lo mostraba en dos versiones diferentes. Descarto que sea el CSS pues que el boton no tiene ningun estilo de posicion asociado en 3.5 y 3.9. He revisado palntillas mustaches pero el boton se agrega mediante el js (showadvanced.js) a partir de la llamada en formslib.php